# Math mode in a `tikz` diagram

Tags: beamer, math-mode, tikz-styles, tikz-arrows, beamer-metropolis

I want a `tikz` diagram, with an arrow connecting bit of text with a bit of math above it.
I had the following, but it doesn't work once "Math" is in a math environment (i.e.:`$Math$`):

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}

\usetheme[progressbar=frametitle]{metropolis}
\usepackage{appendixnumberbeamer}

\usepackage{booktabs}  
\usepackage[scale=2]{ccicons}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{dateplot}

\usepackage{xspace}
\newcommand{\themename}{\textbf{\textsc{metropolis}}\xspace}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,decorations.pathreplacing}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,positioning}

\title{title}
\author{Author}
\date{}


\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Frame Title}
\begin{tikzpicture}
[->,>=stealth',shorten >=1pt,auto,node distance=3cm,
,main node/.style={font=\sffamily\small\bfseries}]

\node[main node] (Text) {Text};
\node[main node,above=.5cm of Text] ($Math$) {$Math$};

\path[]
(Text) edge node [] {\rotatebox[origin=cc]{90}{}} ($Math$);


\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The name of a node and the contents of the node are separate entities, they don't have to be the same text. I'd recommend not using any special characters in the node names, so use for example

```
\node[main node,above=.5cm of Text] (Math) {$Math$};
```

instead of

```
\node[main node,above=.5cm of Text] ($Math$) {$Math$};
```

In addition, note that when you load the `calc` library, you activate the `($ ... $)` syntax for coordinate calculations, which is probably related to the failure here.  For example, if you do

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (Text) {Text};
\node ($Math$)  at (2,0) {$Math$};
%\draw (Text) -- ($Math$);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

this specific example works, but if you uncomment the `\draw` it fails, because TikZ tries to use the `calc` library on the `$Math$` node.